# SQLAlchemy: substitute a view for a table when selecting

Tags: view, sqlalchemy

I've a normal select:

```
e = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.pk=='abc').all()
```

Where MyTable is mapped to `my_table` in db.

I've also created a derived view `my_view` in database that has the exact same named columns as my_table.

Is there a way to substitute in `my_view` for `my_table` at query time so that I get back rows from the view? Obviously the resulting objects would need to be read only - am not intending to alter them.

So basically I'd want the SQL to be

```
FROM my_view AS my_table
```

instead of

```
FROM my_table
```

With everything else the same in the query.

I'd prefer not to create another mapper unless it can be done automatically somehow as MyView has over 60 columns same as MyTable.

---

Update: [`select_entity_from`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=select_entity_from#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_entity_from) seems to be what I need, but in this case it just adds to the FROM tables, instead of replacing:

```
v = Table('my_view', metadata, autoload=True)

print session.query(MyTable).select_entity_from(v).filter(MyTable.pk=='abc')
"SELECT ... FROM my_table, my_view WHERE my_table.pk = 'abc';"
```

But the following only has one FROM entity:

```
print session.query(MyTable).\
    select_entity_from(select([MyTable])).\
    filter(MyTable.pk=='abc')
"SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM my_tabl) AS anon_1 WHERE anon_1.pk = 'abc';"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filed what I thought was a bug: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3933/allow-passing-aliased-to

Final answer was:

```
session.query(MyTable).select_entity_from(
     text('SELECT * FROM my_view').columns(*MyTable.__table__.columns)).\
filter(MyTable.pk=='abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Further digging has got me closer to the answer but no joy. Posting progress here in case it solicits further thoughts:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import aliased
session.query(MyTable).select_entity_from(
    select([aliased(MyTable, alias=v, adapt_on_names=True)])).\
filter(MyTable.pk=='abc')
```

`adapt_on_names` seems to be what I need, and I've double checked that the view has the exact same column names as the table, but the above still produces two `froms`.